# how to call one javascript in another script

Tags: javascript, fckeditor

The below is the java script function that is used to control the audio using keys and now how can i call the normal java script function in the another java script function

```
var editor = document.getElementById("CKEditor1");
editor.on('contentDom', function () {
  editor.document.on('keydown', function (event) {
        if (event.data.key == 32)
            alert('space bar pressed');
   });
});
```

Comment: The code in the ck editor is an anonymous function, so you cant call it untill you give a name to this function and define in a global scope or map it in a global object. But it is an event handler, so is not supposed to be called but when the event is triggered. About calling the function in your second snippet. If the script tag is in the same document and is placed in the head section, you should access to the functions by name. But please explain better what you're looking for.

Comment: please explain how the 2 snippets appear in your page and what You got when you try to use it.

Comment: So why you could not call a function like 'Slow()'? You got an error? You got nothing?

Comment: just make a test with 'Slow()' function. Put the function call directly in your first javascript snippet. In javascript the functions could be called before they are defined. After the test report the error you got, if any.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117637/discussion-between-mario-alexandro-santini-and-xyz).

Comment: Sorry, don't know why this is appening. Anyway, I cant install your app and check it out, sorry. I could only help you if you provide some specific problem. So please, try to call the function as suggested and report the results.

Comment: There is errors or you are sure the code is called (place there a console.log) ?

Answer (score 0):

```
var editor = document.getElementById("CKEditor1");
editor.on('contentDom', function () {
   editor.document.on('keydown', function (event) {
       if (event.data.key == 32)
           alert('space bar pressed');
 });
});
```

Comment: you should change your question, do not write an answer if you don't have one.

Answer (score 0):

You should just call the functions directly as the follow example:

```
 <script  type = "text/javascript">//final
         $(document).ready(function () {
             CKEDITOR.on('instanceCreated', function (e) {
                 e.editor.on('contentDom', function () {
                     e.editor.document.on('keydown', function (event) {
                         var x = event.data.$.keyCode; 
                         if (x == 32) {
                             alert('spacebar is pressed');
                             return true;
                         } else if (x == 115) {
                             if (audio.paused) {
                                 audio.play();//f4
                             } else {
                                 audio.pause()
                             }
                         } else if (x == 119) {
                             // Log before the function
                             console.log("calling Forward()");
                             Forward();//F8
                             // Log after the function
                             console.log("after Forward()");
                          } else if (x == 120) {
                             // Log before the function
                             console.log("calling Slow()");
                             Slow();//F9
                             // Log after the function
                             console.log("after Slow()");
                          }

                         var count = 0;

                     });
                 });
             });

         });

</script>
```

For the other functions you should do a similar work.

As you bind on 'keydown' event, you have to consider the part of your second code snippet :

```
window.addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {
    // space, page up, page down and arrow keys:
    if ([32, 33, 34, 37, 38, 39, 40].indexOf(e.keyCode) > -1) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
}, false);
```

The keycode here are the arrows as the comment says and also you could check easely from this [site](http://keycode.info/).

So you should place here your code:

```
window.addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {
    // space, page up, page down and arrow keys:
    if ([32, 33, 34, 37, 38, 39, 40].indexOf(e.keyCode) > -1) {

        console.log("You pressed " + e.keyCode);

        // I assume right arrow for forward
        if (x == 39) {
            // Log before the function
            console.log("calling Forward()");
            Forward();//F8
            // Log after the function
            console.log("after Forward()");
         } else if (x == 37) { // left arrow to slow
            // Log before the function
            console.log("calling Slow()");
            Slow();//F9
            // Log after the function
            console.log("after Slow()");
         }

         // then prevent to continue the other event handlers to avoid scrolling.
        e.preventDefault();
    }
}, false);
```

Comment: Just call the functions you need in the place where you need, as I did with the 'Slow()', and is should work.

Comment: @xyz I changed my answer, providing an example on how you should change your code. Hope this helps.

Comment: If you don't see the logs it means the code is not executed, so check if the handle is called and the keycode value. Put a log before the first 'if' to debug it.

Comment: You could log the keycode of the key you want and then change the code to do something. For example [this site](http://keycode.info/) offer you a shortcut to capture the keycode of all the keys you need.